# MS Excel Simple Formula Query

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel sheet which has almost 100 columns with Column header names:

[image: spreadsheet]

In this image, 11 column header values/names starting from A to L. (A is at `B2`).
What I want is a formula to put in 'Results' column `X` which displays all Column Header names which have value "1" in it.
You can see the first 'Results' cell value has A,C,F,H,J because they contain "1" in it.

I tried doing it by an `IF` formula but using that way I need to put `IF` for each and every column value which will be a nasty task as I got more than 100 columns so want a mechanism to simply select the range and apply it.

Not expert in VBA but if that has to be the solution then given the code I can copy paste that.

Any questions let me know please.

Comment: I had attached excel screenshot image but can't see it here. In case if you don't find it let me know please and I will find a way to upload. thanks again.

Comment: The results you show in column X seem to be missing all of the applicable K and L values.  Is this just oversight in the example, failure of the formula you're trying, or a more complex rule than what is described?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should suffice.

The formula for row "a1" is: `=CONCATENATE(O2,IF(B2=1,B$1,""))` which will be pasted 2 columns to the right of the last column in this example. Copy this formula (with its proper reference), and then paste it into all remaining cells after initial formula is in place. Note the $ symbol, this is important for the copy/paste.

`=CONCATENATE(O2,IF(B2=1,B$1,""))`

-- the `O2` reference above, in your case might be `FW`, `FX`, ...or `AAB` depending how many columns you have of course.

Then simply reference the last column as the RESULT; shows in the bottom half of the image. In this example: `=AA2`

You will have to skip a column. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: @John Glad to have helped out. If the solution worked out, please don't forget to click on the Light colored check mark next to the Zero on the solution to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a user defined function UDF in VBA and use it as function in column X
The code is the following create a new module in your workbook

`Public Function concatcell(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As Range, RowNumber As Integer)`
 `Dim i As Long`
 `Dim J As Long`
 `Dim Result As String`
 `Result = ""`
 `J = LookupRange.Columns.Count`
    `For i = 1 To J`

`If LookupRange.Cells(RowNumber, i) = Lookupvalue Then`
 `Result = Result & LookupRange.Cells(1, i) & ";"`
 `End If`
 `Next i`
  `concatcell = Result`
 `End Function`

In X2 write:
`=concatcell(1,$B$1:$L2,ROW())`
drag it down
$B$1:$L2 is the first 2 rows change it to your data references but keep $ as is to make the range change automatically (Row B contains the label to return) 
1 is the value you are looking for
Row() is the row number to change automatically as you drag it down
**Remember to save the workbook as macro enabled** (in order to make work next time you open it)

Answer (score -1):

The formula you need to use is quite simple, albeit long. Here is the formula (which should go in `N2` and than be dragged down until where you have data):

`=IF(B2>0,$B$1&";","")&IF(C2>0,$C$1&";","")&IF(D2>0,$D$1&";","")&IF(E2>0,$E$1&";","")&IF(F2>0,$F$1&";","")&IF(G2>0,$G$1&";","")&IF(H2>0,$H$1&";","")&IF(I2>0,$I$1&";","")&IF(J2>0,$J$1&";","")&IF(K2>0,$K$1&";","")&IF(L2>0,$L$1&";","")&IF(M2>0,$M$1&";","")`

(It is a bit different than your example because I see you missed the `D` header.)

What it does is simple, for each coulmn it checks the cell in this row if it has a velue greater than zero, if true it brings over the coulmn name with a semicolon, and if not it leaves empty.

I upladed a sample document with the formula ready over here if you wanna see it https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ao8EzDmtlA0JhibEB9Wnq4GkXapp

Comment: I think this is the same formula he has already used.

Comment: Oops, I misread his question, thought that he was referring to 100 rows.